# Filtering with help of two columns from a TSV file

Tags: awk, grep

I have the following file:

```
Pepper1.55ch01  PGA1.55 gene    63209   63880   .       -       .       ID=CA01g00010;Name=CA01g00010
Pepper1.55ch01  PGA1.55 mRNA    63209   63880   .       -       .       ID=mRNA.CA01g00010;Parent=CA01g00010;Note="Detected protein of unknown function"
Pepper1.55ch01  PGA1.55 exon    63209   63300   .       -       .       ID=exon:CA01g00010:1;Parent=mRNA.CA01g00010
Pepper1.55ch01  PGA1.55 CDS     63209   63300   .       -       0       ID=CDS:CA01g00010:1;Parent=mRNA.CA01g00010
Pepper1.55ch01  PGA1.55 exon    63445   63730   .       -       .       ID=exon:CA01g00010:2;Parent=mRNA.CA01g00010
Pepper1.55ch01  PGA1.55 CDS     63445   63730   .       -       0       ID=CDS:CA01g00010:2;Parent=mRNA.CA01g00010
Pepper1.55ch01  PGA1.55 exon    63758   63880   .       -       .       ID=exon:CA01g00010:3;Parent=mRNA.CA01g00010
Pepper1.55ch01  PGA1.55 CDS     63758   63880   .       -       0       ID=CDS:CA01g00010:3;Parent=mRNA.CA01g00010

Pepper1.55ch01  PGA1.55 gene    112298  112938  .       -       .       ID=CA01g00020;Name=CA01g00020
Pepper1.55ch01  PGA1.55 mRNA    112298  112938  .       -       .       ID=mRNA.CA01g00020;Parent=CA01g00020;Note="PREDICTED: protein ECERIFERUM 3-like [Solanum tuberosum]"
Pepper1.55ch01  PGA1.55 exon    112298  112457  .       -       .       ID=exon:CA01g00020:1;Parent=mRNA.CA01g00020
Pepper1.55ch01  PGA1.55 CDS     112298  112457  .       -       0       ID=CDS:CA01g00020:1;Parent=mRNA.CA01g00020
Pepper1.55ch01  PGA1.55 exon    112565  112743  .       -       .       ID=exon:CA01g00020:2;Parent=mRNA.CA01g00020
Pepper1.55ch01  PGA1.55 CDS     112565  112743  .       -       0       ID=CDS:CA01g00020:2;Parent=mRNA.CA01g00020
Pepper1.55ch01  PGA1.55 exon    112828  112938  .       -       .       ID=exon:CA01g00020:3;Parent=mRNA.CA01g00020
Pepper1.55ch01  PGA1.55 CDS     112828  112938  .       -       0       ID=CDS:CA01g00020:3;Parent=mRNA.CA01g00020
...
```

Now I want to extract ID (e.g. CA01g00010) from column 9 if column 3 is a gene. However, the below awk/grep commands delivered different amounts of ids.

```
> awk '{print $3,$9}' Pepper_1.55.gene_models-1-12.gff3 | grep gene | wc -l
30265

> awk '{print $3}' Pepper_1.55.gene_models-1-12.gff3 | grep gene | wc -l
30242
```

It appears that column 9 sometimes contain the gene. What did I miss?

Comment: It's not clear what the question is. Are you trying to find only the lines where the word occurs in the third column? As a substring, or exact match? Your current attempt searches for a substring in any column. (Perhaps see also [useless use of `grep`.](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep))

Comment: replace the `grep|wc` with `sort > file[12]` (different output file for each `awk` call), `diff` the two files and what do you get? alternatively, run `comm -13 file1 file2` and `comm -23 file1 file2`; objective is to review the differences and determine the accuracy of the current code at fining just the rows you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to extract ID (e.g. `CA01g00010`) from column `9` if column `3` is a `gene`

You may use this `awk` solution:

```sh
awk -F '\t' '$3 == "gene" {gsub(/^ID=|;.*/, "", $9); print $9}' file.tsv

CA01g00010
CA01g00020
```

**Details:**

- `-F '\t'`: This `awk` command uses `\t` (tab) as input field separator.
- `$3 == "gene"`: When `$3` is `gene` then take an action
- `{...}` is action block that contains:

  - `gsub(/^ID=|;.*/, "", $9)`: Remove initial `ID=` part and anything that comes after `;` from `$9`
  - `print $9`: print `$9`

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk -F'\t' $3 == "gene" && $9 ~ /^ID=/ && split($9,array,"[=;]"){print array[2]}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, making field separator as TAB here for all the lines of Input_file. Then in main program, checking condition if 3rd column is gene AND 9th column starts from ID= AND splitting 9th column into array named array with delimiters of `=;` and printing 2nd element of line's 9th column.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- don't have to worry about case insenstive matches (eg, don't have to match on `GENE` or `Gene`)
- a match in column 9 can be further stipulated as the column starting with `ID=CA01g00010;`
- OP's current objective appears to be the collection of a count of matching rows; otherwise OP should update question to state the desired output (eg, print the entire line? print a subset of columns?)

Modifying OP's sample input to provide a mix of matches and non-matches:

```
$ cat input.dat
Pepper1.55ch01  PGA1.55 gene    63209   63880   .       -       .       ID=CA01g00010;Name=CA01g00010
Pepper1.55ch01  PGA1.55 exon    63209   63880   .       -       .       ID=CA01g00010; skipme; Name=CA01g00010

Pepper1.55ch01  PGA1.55 gene    63209   63300   .       -       .       skipme; ID=CA01g00010:1;Parent=mRNA.CA01g00010
Pepper1.55ch01  PGA1.55 CDS     63758   63880   .       -       0       ID=CDS:CA01g00010:3;Parent=mRNA.CA01g00010

Pepper1.55ch01  PGA1.55 gene    112298  112938  .       -       .       ID=CA01g00020;Name=CA01g00020
Pepper1.55ch01  PGA1.55 exon    112298  112457  .       -       .       ID=exon:CA01g00020:1;Parent=mRNA.CA01g00020

Pepper1.55ch01  PGA1.55 gene    112298  112938  .       -       .       ID=DE03g00230; skipme; Name=CA01g00020
Pepper1.55ch01  PGA1.55 exon    112298  112457  .       -       .       ID=exon:CA01g00020:1;Parent=mRNA.CA01g00020

Pepper1.55ch01  PGA1.55 gene    63209   63880   .       -       .       ID=CA01g00010;Name=CA01g00010
Pepper1.55ch01  PGA1.55 exon    63209   63880   .       -       .       ID=CA01g00010; skipme; Name=CA01g00010
```

One `awk` idea that replaces OP's current `awk|grep|wc` code:

```
awk -F'\t' -v col3="${col3}" -v id="${id}" '       # allow OP to define search strings for column 3 and the "ID=" match in column 9
$3 == col3 && match($9,"ID="id";")==1 { cnt++ }    # if we find both matches then increment our counter
END { print cnt+0 }                                # "+0" to force default value from empty string to 0
' input.dat
```

For `bash` variables `col3='gene'` and `id=CA01g00010` we get:

```
2
```

For `bash` variables `col3='gene'` and `id='DE03g00230'` we get:

```
1
```

For `bash` variables `col3='gene'` and `id='findme'` we get:

```
0
```